# JavaScript - new Object, code in moduls

Tags: javascript, module, iife

I'm starting with JavaScript and studied the following code. What does the new operater do? Is not the canvas.js calling itself and creates a canvas?

main.js

```
(function(){
     new display.Canvas();

})();
```

canvas.js

```
(function(){

var Canvas = display.Canvas = function() {

    this.createCanvas();

};
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Douglas Crockford has a good article on [how "new" works](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/).

In the example you give, the code in canvas.js (assuming the `display.canvas` should actually be `display.Canvas`) is defining a function for how a new canvas is created. The main.js code uses that function to create a Canvas.

Comment: Thank You @ Dan !!! quick answer and good link, thanks a lot !!!